# GtKGLArea unable to create OpenGL 2.1 context

Tags: opengl, gtk, gtk3, gnome, gtkmm3

i'm currently working on a simple editor for my game engine project, while the project seems to run just fine on my main workstation ( GTX 650Ti with OpenGL 3.3+ support ) , but it'seems to be broken when im test it on my testing desktop ( GMA4500 with OpenGL 2.1 max support ).

The GtkGLArea's `gtk_gl_area_make_current()` unable to create OpenGL 2.1 context even if i specified the GL version with `gtk_gl_area_set_required_version()` to 2.1.

Tried to troubleshoot it with testing the gtk glarea demo ( https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/demos/gtk-demo/glarea.c ) and getting the same result.

Already search it on the web but none lead to any solution. Though someone have mention the same exatct issue on glarea example from ebassi (https://github.com/ebassi/glarea-example/issues/2)

Is there any solution to this?

Operating System: Fedora 23
GTK version 3.18

---

**EDIT :**
The Operating system (Fedora 23) are using OpenGL 2.1 ( checked with glxinfo ), and considering by demos given on GTK+ source i'm assuming GTK using GL 3.0+ as default. <s>is it any way to overide this?</s> (according to ebassi on his answer below, starting from GTK+ 3.20 `GdkGLContext` will falling back to legacy profiles if core profiles are not available. will test it as soon i upgrade to GTK+ 3.20)

**EDIT 2:**
I'm able to make workaround by using context created by SDL instead of `GdkGLContext`, but i'm still intrested to make `GdkGLContext` to work with OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: This question probably doesn't belong on SO because it sounds more like an OS problem, but have you tried running `glxinfo`? It should tell you what version your OS is actually using. Also, could you be more specific about the exact error, behavior, response, etc.

Comment: The OS is using OGL 2.1, default context creation are running just fine on other lib (glfw, wxWidget and qt). So i dont think it was issue caused by the os.

Comment: Well, if it's not an OS problem, we'll need to know the exact behavior.

Answer (score 4):

GTK+ tries to created an OpenGL 3.2+ core profile context by default.

Starting from GTK+ 3.20, `GdkGLContext` will attempt at falling back to legacy profiles if core profiles are not available. You can check whether a `GdkGLContext` is in legacy mode by using [`gdk_gl_context_is_legacy()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkGLContext.html#gdk-gl-context-is-legacy).

You are not allowed to select a legacy context by yourself, because it's not possible to share core profiles with legacy ones, and GDK creates GL contexts internally for drawing.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I guess i'll try to upgrade the GTK+ to 3.20 first to see if i can use legacy mode on `GdkGLContext`

Answer (score 0):

You can use EGL to use legacy (pre-3.0) OpenGL versions with GtkDrawingArea

http://bobthegnome.blogspot.com/2014/09/using-egl-with-gtk.html