# Compilation failure in vertex shader unless MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.0 is set

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glsl, mesa

I'm trying to run this GL demo but it only runs in CentOS 7 if I set `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.0` as shown here:

```
git clone https://github.com/ebassi/glarea-example.git
make
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.0 ./glarea
```

Without that environment variable I get this error:
[image: Compilation failure in vertex shader 1.1 1.2 1.3 is not uspported]

I've tried changing `#version` to 110 and 120 but then it fails to compile.

#### Questions:

- Shouldn't the GL version be detected somehow?
- What is the proper way set this up to build this as a cross-platform OpenGL application to run on many different Linux distro's?

#### Vertex and fragment code are as follows:

```
==> glarea-fragment.glsl <==
#version 130

smooth in vec4 vertexColor;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main() {
  outputColor = vertexColor;
}

==> glarea-vertex.glsl <==
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;

uniform mat4 mvp;

smooth out vec4 vertexColor;

void main() {
  gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
  vertexColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting the version of the shaders to "#version 300 es" and see if that works? GLSL ES 3.0 is somewhat similar to desktop GLSL >= 130, so it just might work without otherwise modifying the shader code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed the part describing what [MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html) actually does:

> changes the value returned by glGetString(GL_VERSION) and possibly the GL API type. 
> ...  
> Mesa may **not really implement** all the features of the given version. (for developers only)

This means that but *forcing* an OpenGL version reported my Mesa you are just get lucky that specific DEMO is running / running well, as Mesa doesn't implement some features of required version and may crash or misbehave.

- Mesa implements a list of OpenGL drivers for different devices at different levels. So that the version reported by OpenGL without overriding depends on graphics device.
- Furthermore, Mesa has different progress in implementing OpenGL of particular version of particular graphics card. So that upgrading Mesa might bring newer OpenGL version (though upgrading Mesa usually requires upgrading Linux; but if you are running on a real hardware - you may try proprietary graphics drivers instead).
- In addition, Mesa implements different levels of OpenGL **Compatible** and [**Core Profiles**](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#OpenGL_3.2_and_Profiles). Modern applications might use higher OpenGL versions when requesting **Core Profile**. You may check the difference by running `glxinfo` that reports information about both Core and Compatible Profiles on your system.

So that returning to the questions.

> Shouldn't the GL version be detected somehow?

Yes, normally applications are expected to check `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and terminate with a meaningful message if version is lower than supported (instead of trying to compiler GLSL program of unsupported version as in case of this sample).

> What is the proper way set this up to build this as a cross-platform OpenGL application to run on many different Linux distro's?

It is not the question about *building* an application, but about the very *development* of it. To be more compatible, application should support lower versions of OpenGL that it could run on. In this particular case I guess that it would be a minor effort to make code compatible with OpenGL 2.1.

But at the same time, newer [GTK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909072/gtkglarea-unable-to-create-opengl-2-1-context) create a Core Profile instead of Compatible Profile by default, so that a portable application should be able to handle both (by providing different GLSL programs / handling missing GL functions etc.).

I don't know much about CentOS 7, but it looks pretty old (released in '2014) - I guess the referred sample would run just fine on most modern Linux distros without modifications (with newer Mesa and newer GTK).

Comment: CentOS 7 has Gtk 3.22, which includes the fallback to compatibility mode. So it should be possible to modify the code to work on an older system. But like you point out, a newer distro would likely have a newer Mesa which would provide higher GL version support.